# Understanding Java Callbacks/Events in Matlab

Tags: java, matlab, events, proxy, listener

I am trying to understand more fundamentally what is happening when adding listeners in Matlab to java objects.  See [here](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/matlab-callbacks-for-java-events) for original discussion.

Below is an java src for setting up the callback

```
public class Handler {

    public Listener object;

    public class Event extends java.util.EventObject {
        public double d1,d2,d3;
        Event(Object obj, double d1, double d2, double d3) {
            super(obj); this.d1 = d1; this.d2 = d2; this.d3 = d3;
        }}

    public interface Listener extends java.util.EventListener {
        // the function call matlab proxy obj implements
        void measurement(Event event);
    }

    public void addListener   (Listener listener) {
        System.out.println("listener has been added");
        this.object = listener;
    }

    public void removeListener(Listener listener) {
        System.out.println("listener has been removed");
        this.object = null;
    }

    // wrapper function (i.e. what actually exposed/called/used)
    public void measurement(double temp, double pressure, double height) {
        this.object.measurement( new Event(this, temp, pressure, height) );
        System.out.println("listener has been notified");
    }
}
```

Then in Matlab (2014b) can set up the Java --> Matlab callback as

```
% create Handler java object in matlab
handler = com.callback.Handler();

% add a listener for interface function measurement(e)
addlistener(handler,'measurement',@(h,e)disp(e.d1+e.d2+e.d3));

% call the wrapper function manually to test setup
handler.measurement(1,2,3);
```

Some idea of the initial setup of Matlab's `addlistener` call is performed by

```
 /toolbox/matlab/uitools/private/javaaddlistener.m
```

When calling `addlistener` in Matlab I get the message on the command window that

> listener has been added

from the `addListener` function in `Handler`.  So here Matlab has dynamically created an object which implements `Listener` interface and has called

```
handler.addListener(mysteryObj);
```

I can try to see what Matlab put there with

```
>> handler.object
```

which returns

> com.mathworks.MLEventAdapters.com.callback.Handler$ListenerLIAdapterClass@45a37759

which I guess is some kind of dynamically created [proxy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) object?

The most vexing issues here is that once I look at `>> handler.object` suddenly I see the message

> listener has been removed

but why?? This means Matlab automatically called

```
handler.removeListener(mysteryObj)
```

here?

At any rate, I started looking through com.mathworks.jmi but that's going to take a while and I'm not even certain the answer is there ... any help would be great.